# Proof that $\lim_{x\to\infty} b^x=0 \iff 0 \leq b<1$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, exponential-function

Are there any errors in the following attempt to prove the above?

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $f(x)=b^x$, with $0 \leq b<1$. Then, for all $x$, $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)=b^x \ln(b)<0$. This means that $f$ is decreasing and bounded below by 0, and so $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$.

($\Rightarrow)$ Let $f(x)=b^x$. In order for $f$ to be defined, $b \geq 0$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that, for all $x$, $x>N \implies |f(x)-0|=f(x)<\epsilon$. This can be the case only if $0 \leq b<1$.

Comment: I certainly agree with the backwards proof, although I cannot say I am familiar with the notation in the forwards one.

Comment: You need to be more careful about the pre-conditions on $b$. If $b < 0$, then $b^x$ is undefined for $x \in \mathbb R$. More importantly, if $b = 0$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} b^x$ is certainly $0$; but it is not the case that $0 < b < 1$. So what you are trying to prove is in fact false.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I've changed the post to try to reflect your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $\implies$ is not solid. I think that it is better to do it by contraposition. If $b \ge 1$, then $b^x = \exp(x \log b) \ge \exp(0) = 1$ for all $x \ge 0$. So $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted your answer. Can you say what is not solid about the $\implies$?

Comment: You are welcome. Not that there is something wrong with it, but it isn't clear why $0 < b < 1$ would follow from what preceded. It would follow, but not in a straightforward manner. IMHO that is an incomplete proof.

Answer (score 0):

A different thought on this, probably not as rigorous as Ahmed's.
If $0<b<1$ then we can write $b=\frac{p}{q}$ where $q>p$. There exist a (fractional) value of $r>0$ such that $q=pr$ so that we can write $b=\frac{p}{pr}=\frac{1}{r}$ Now consider $(\frac{1}{r})^x=\frac{1}{r^x}$ when $x$ goes to infinity

Comment: What if $b=\sqrt{2}-1$?

Comment: An irrational number always lies between two rational numbers and so a rational number can be picked such that it is still less than 1 but more than your example. However, point well taken, it did not occur to me when writing up my post.